# React : multiple asynchroous state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've writing bellow example. his aim is to add asynchronously entries in an array contained in a React state.

My problem is my callback errase previous values rather than add them...

My runnable exemple is available here : https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-kirch-7rtup?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

how to optain expected result ?

thanks

Comment: Please ensure your whole question (including any necessary code) is **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: You can put a runnable React example in the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are overwriting each enqueued state update since all the state updates are enqueued within the same render cycle. You are also mutating state with the array::push.

```
const callback = (newValue) => {
  const newState = clone(state);
  newState.myValue.push(newValue); // <-- state mutation!
  setState(newState);
};

const exe = () => {
  setTimeout(() => callback("b"), 1000); // <-- all updates from current state!
  setTimeout(() => callback("c"), 2000);
  setTimeout(() => callback("d"), 3000);
};
```

## Solution

Use functional state updates to correctly update from previous state.

```
const callback = (newValue) => {
  setState(state => ({
    ...state, // <-- copy existing state
    myValue: [...state.myValue, newValue], // <-- copy array and append new value
  }));
};
```

Comment: If this is the problem (description matches it), then there are several duplicates you could point to.